# Remove all default panoramas in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to collectively disable all StreetView panoramas provided by Google, so that only custom ones show up?

The following code was suggested in a different thread but only targets one specific map-bound panorama:

```
var panorama = map.getStreetView();
panorama.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: How do you define a custom panorama?  Is it one **you** created?  Or something else?  How are you "showing them" (what do you mean by "show up")?

Comment: @geocodezip Exactly. When dragging the Streetview Pegman, all public panoramas are indicated by blue markers. My goal is to disable those and only show custom ones as [documented here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-custom-simple)